# Check inputs with same value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to check if inputs have the same value

the inputs are generated by a loop the number is variant every time

```
for(int i = 0; i< add; i++) 
{%>
<input  name="<%= i%>" id="<%= i%>" class="form-control" holder="S/Num"/>
<%} %>
```

I tried this with but it didn't work

```
<script>
$('input').blur(function() {
  if ($('#s1').attr('value') == $('#s2').attr('value')) {
    alert('Same Value'); return false;
  } else { return true; }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var nums = $('input.form-control[id^=s]'); /* find all inputs starting id with `s` */
  nums.on('change', function(e) {
    var map = {};
    nums.each(function(i, el) {
      if (el.value.replace(/\s/g, '')) { /* trim whitespace */
        if (undefined !== map[el.value]) {
          console.log('duplicate value', el.value, ', found input with id', el.id);
          el.value = ''; /* reset, if required */
        } else {
          map[el.value] = 1;
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="s1" id="s1" class="form-control" placeholder="S/Num" />
<input name="s2" id="s2" class="form-control" placeholder="S/Num" />
<input name="s3" id="s3" class="form-control" placeholder="S/Num" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the *value attribute* is useless. It is not updated when user edits the field. It is only used to tell browser what initial value is. You need the *value property* using `val()`.

```
   $('input').blur(function() {
        if ($('#s1').val() == $('#s2').val()) {
        alert('Same Value'); return false;
        } else { return true; }
    });
```

If you want to compare an unknown number of elements for duplicate values use an array

```
$('input').blur(function() {
   var values = []
   $('input').each(function(){
      if(!values.includes(this.value)){
        values.push(this.value)
      }else{
        alert('Name:' + this.name +' is duplicate');        
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: didin't work for both. when I write in input 1 and go to write in input 2 it pop up duplicate input 2 still empty

Comment: Oh...I did forget to check for empty values. You should add that in

Comment: Also add a class to the inputs you want checked in this loop and use that as selector. $('input') could find other fields if you have them in page

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, hope this will help you and you can change this with your requirement:

```
 var valid = true;
 $.each($('input'), function (index1, item1) {
     $.each($('input').not(this), function (index2, item2) {
         if ($(item1).val() == $(item2).val()) {
              valid = false;
         }

     });
 });
 if(valid == false)
 {
   alert("Same Value");
 }
 return valid;
```